# ESLint CLI with --rule option

Tags: command-line-interface, eslint

I'm having trouble using the ESLint CLI with the `--rule` option.

```bash
# This is what I tried
eslint --rule "{no-console: error}" --fix-dry-run .
```

Resulting in the following error:

> Invalid value for option 'rule' - expected type Object, received value: {no-console:.

What is the right way of using the `--rule` option? I have ESLint installed locally and use `npx` to run it.

- Node.js version 14.15.0
- ESLint version 7.14.0
- OS Windows 10

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/vue'
  ],
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with `npx` and Windows. Explained in [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13733) removing the spaces inside `--rule` solves the issue:

```bash
npx eslint --rule "no-console:error" --fix-dry-run .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `"no-console": ["error"]` in `.eslintrc.js` rules

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'no-console': ['error']
  }
};
```

and just run

```
eslint --fix-dry-run ./
```

or

```
eslint --rule "no-console: ['error']" --fix-dry-run .
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#-rule

Comment: I'd like to apply the `no-console` rule only when running from the command line. However, doing `--rule "no-console: ['error']"` doesn't seem to work for me. Getting `No files matching the pattern "['error']" were found`.